# SubEthaSMTP Unexpected error in the SMTP handler thread NoClassDefFoundError jakarta/mail/internet/AddressException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

SubEthaSMTP server running fine on port 25001. After a successful authentication from my client code to Subethasmtp server i am having this error message org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session: Unexpected error in the SMTP handler thread
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/mail/internet/AddressException

This is my SMTPServerConfig class

```
 @Configuration
 public class SMTPServerConfig {

    private final SMTPServer smtpServer;
    private final SimpleMessageListener marketingMsgListener;
    private final UsernamePasswordValidator authValidator;
    private final EasyAuthenticationHandlerFactory easyAuth;

    public SMTPServerConfig(SimpleMessageListener marketingMsgListener) {
       authValidator = new SimpleAuthValidatorImpl();
       easyAuth = new EasyAuthenticationHandlerFactory(authValidator);
       this.marketingMsgListener = marketingMsgListener;

       this.smtpServer = SMTPServer
            .port(25001)
            .simpleMessageListener(this.marketingMsgListener)
            .requireAuth(true)
            .authenticationHandlerFactory(easyAuth)
            .hostName("localhost")
            .hideTLS(false)
            .enableTLS(true)
            .requireTLS(false)
            .requireAuth(true)
            .connectionTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .maxMessageSize(10000)
            .maxConnections(20)
            .build();

       this.smtpServer.stop();
       this.smtpServer.start();
   }
```

I am using usernamepasswordvalidator

```
 @Configuration
 public class SimpleAuthValidatorImpl implements UsernamePasswordValidator {

   private final String CREDENTIALS_LOGIN = "christclau";
   private final String CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD = "password";

   @Override
   public void login(String username, String password, MessageContext context) throws LoginFailedException {
      if(CREDENTIALS_LOGIN.equals(username) && CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD.equals(password)){
        System.out.println("yes Authenticated successfully");
      }else{
        System.err.println("no Invalid authentication !");
        throw new LoginFailedException();
      }
   }
 }
```

This is my mail client to send message to the server

```
 public void sendMail(Mail mail) {
    final String username = "christclau";
    final String password = "password";

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "25001");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    //prop.put("mail.debug", "true");
    //prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //TLS
    
    Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
    session.setDebug(true);

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mail.getFrom()));
        message.setRecipients(
                Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(mail.getTo())
        );
        message.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
        message.setText("HI you have done sending mail with outlook");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

This is the output message

```
 DEBUG: setDebug: Jakarta Mail version 1.6.7
 DEBUG: getProvider() returningjavax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
 DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
 DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=localhost, user=MY PC, password=<null>
 DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
 DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 25001, isSSL false 220 localhost ESMTP SubEthaSMTP null
 DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "localhost", port: 25001
 EHLO DESKTOP-FFJA5IP
 250-localhost
 250-8BITMIME
 250-SIZE 10000
 250-STARTTLS
 250-CHUNKING
 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
 250 Ok
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10000"
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "Ok", arg ""
 DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=localhost, user=christclau, password=<non-null>
 DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2
 DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
 DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
 yes Authenticated successfully
 DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
 DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
 MAIL FROM:<christoozu@gmail.com>
 2022-02-26 11:21:40.081 ERROR 9452 --- [127.0.0.1:50466] org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session      : Unexpected error in the SMTP handler thread

 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/mail/internet/AddressException
 at org.subethamail.smtp.internal.command.MailCommand.execute(MailCommand.java:74) ~[subethasmtp-6.0.1.jar:na]
at org.subethamail.smtp.internal.server.RequireTLSCommandWrapper.execute(RequireTLSCommandWrapper.java:32) ~[subethasmtp-6.0.1.jar:na]
at org.subethamail.smtp.internal.server.RequireAuthCommandWrapper.execute(RequireAuthCommandWrapper.java:35) ~[subethasmtp-6.0.1.jar:na]
at org.subethamail.smtp.internal.server.CommandHandler.handleCommand(CommandHandler.java:86) ~[subethasmtp-6.0.1.jar:na]
at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.runCommandLoop(Session.java:261) ~[subethasmtp-6.0.1.jar:na]
at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.run(Session.java:170) ~[subethasmtp-6.0.1.jar:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.mail.internet.AddressException
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
... 9 common frames omitted
```

This is my dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.davidmoten</groupId>
        <artifactId>subethasmtp</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.6 and earlier still use the `javax.mail` namespace for JakartaMail (formerly JavaMail), while your SubEtha SMTP version seems to expect the `jakarta.mail` namespace. Spring Boot explicitly specifies versions of the JakartaMail package, see [Spring Boot Dependency Versions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions) and search for jakarta.mail. For Spring Boot 2.6.4, it lists version 1.6.7, and that version is still based on the `javax.mail` namespace.

You need to downgrade SubEtha SMTP to a version that still uses the `javax.mail` namespace of JakartaMail/JavaMail, and wait for Spring Boot 3 before using a version that needs the `jakarta.mail` namespace.

In theory, you can also set the Maven property `jakarta-mail.version` to 2.0.1, but this could cause problems in other parts of Spring Boot, so I do not recommend that.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate. version 4.0.1 worked perfectly.